# PowerShell array not showing spaces ('n) in email when using Send-MailMessage and shows * at the top when using import-csv?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a script I'm running that generates and emails a report based on backups copied and held in our environment. What I am doing to format this report is creating a body array to include the various contents shown in the report, and in order to format the data (name and lastwritetime of backups on the server), I am using the 'select name, select lastwritetime | export-csv' and then import-csv at the end into the body array with ConverTo-Html -Fragment. This formats all the data appropriately:

```
$body = @()
"" | Out-File C:\files\PrimaryBody.csv -append
```

**Code here that grabs the backup issues**

```
("The number of backups that were not successfully copied are " + $warningErrorCount + ". ") | Out-File C:\files\PrimaryBody.csv -append

$BackupIssues | Out-File C:\files\PrimaryBody.csv -append


$OutofDateBackups | select name, LastWriteTime | export-csv -path C:\files\OutDatedBackups.csv -append -Force  

$body+= " " 

$body+= "'n"

$body+= Import-Csv -Path C:\files\PrimaryBody.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment


$body+= Import-Csv -Path C:\files\OutDatedBackups.csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

The result in the email, when send-mailmessage command is run is the following:

```
*
The number of backups that were not successfully copied are 13. 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

(I have included X just to cover up data :) )

However, my issue lies in that the body array will not allow an empty line/space to be shown in the email.. I have tried many things, including `$body += " ", $body+= "'n", $body+= "'r'n"` all it would do is either ignore the empty space entirely or it would literally write the 'n in the body of the email. I am not sure why It won't allow me to add an empty space/line in the email. Secondly, no matter what I do, there is always a * reported at the top of the report as shown above, before the data in the import-csv is written. I am not sure why this is and have been unable to remove it. Please help if possible!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The ```'n``` issue is because powershell uses the “backtick” character for escape sequences, but you’re using the “single quote” (apostrophe) character. For line breaks in normal strings, use \`n or \`r\`n. For html use ```<br/>``` as per the answer below...

Answer (score 2):

you are using partial body as html. Then don't use array and use `<br />` tags as line breaks. Like this:

```
$body = "First line"
$body += "<br />"
```

And while sending the mail use the `-BodyAsHtml` switch parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use arrays for the body parameter of Send-MailMessage.  If you look at the help for the command, you'll see that the parameter is `[[-Body] <string>]` and not `[[-Body] <string[]>]`  Your problem is that you're not using a string parameter.  If you build your parameter as a string and then use the newline/return characters, you'll be fine.  So this will work just fine:

```
$Body = "First line of text"
$Body += "`r`nSecond line of text"
```

A more efficient way of doing this in PowerShell is to use the StringBuilder .NET class.  Here's a link to an article I like on this topic [Powershell: Concatenate strings using StringBuilder](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-11-20-Powershell-StringBuilder/).  The StringBuilder is faster than += adding to a string.  The syntax is a bit odd, but it grows on you.  The same data in StringBuilder would be:

```
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
[void]$sb.Append('First line of text')
[void]$sb.AppendLine('Second line of text')
```

To use the data as a string, you need to use the `.ToString()` method like this:

```
$sb.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for following up, Matthew.